# Best practices on error handling in Scala using Try

Tags: scala

I have handled exception as follows:

```
def calculate(input: Option[Double]): Try[String] =
  Try {
    input match {
      case (Some(value)) => value.toString
      case (None) => throw new IllegalArgumentException("No value found")
    }
}
```

And in client code:

```
val result = calculate(....)

result match {
    case Success(i) => println(i)
    case Failure(s) => throw s // or log(s) to log the issue and continue
}
```

Is it good enough practice or much better can be done for clean and elegant code base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Try` usually used to cover parts which might throw an error, like in cases if you are using some Java libs, which can throw an exception. But, if you would like to return possible error and force client to handle it, `Either[A, B]` is much better option, at least because you can specify more precise error type for `Left[A]` and safely to pattern match over your's `A` type, instead of do possibly incorrect pattern matching against some `Throwable`, like you would do for `Failure(t)`.

So, in your  case possible solution would look like:

```
sealed trait CalculationError
case class Error1(cause: String) extends CalculationError

def calculate(input: Option[Double]): Either[CalculationError, String] =
    input match {
      case (Some(value)) => Right(value.toString)
      case (None) => Left(Error1("No value found"))
    }
}

val result = calculate(....)

result match {
    case Right(i) => println(i)
    case Left(Error1(s)) => println(s)
}
```

This is safer approach, because you can later add another type of error , say `case class Error2(cause: String) extends CalculationError` and on client pattern matching code part, compile will show a warn message that you missed handling of new error: `Match is not exhaustive`. In case of `Failure(t)` compile won't be able suggest such warning, so it's easier to make mistake on error handling side.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Option#toRight` might shorten it like so: `input.map(_.toString).toRight(Error1("No value found"))`

Comment: No need to fix it, it is just an alternative :)

Comment: While handling case Right, if we want to assign i to some variable and use it later on, then it violates immutability. Can we avoid it somehow?

Comment: @Mandroid Thank you for a comment, Could you provide more details how `result` will be used? Is this part of HTTP request handling, CLI app arguments handling, message handling from some queue or you are interesting about about abstract response?

Comment: So basically I am iterating a Seq, and for each element I call calculate. If result of calculate has error,then I would log the error and move to next element, ELSE I would use value inside Right for further processing and results of those computations are put inside another object, which is then returned to client.

Comment: @Mandroid is this `Seq[Option[Double]]` or just `Seq[Double]`?

Comment: Seq contains other type of object, which contains Option[Double].